# how to create Table Partitioning Dynamically based on Single Column which is of type varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Can any one help me in creating Partition on my large table. Our large table will have around billions of data, we would be performing some cursor operations on top of this large table. Performance is very slow when we run query on top of this table. We heard Partitioning can help us by non blocking call, incase of any large insertion /updating happens. I need one quick way to partition my table based on varchar data column, like this column will have data ofCountries , I would like to create partition like all data belonging to USA as One Partition and NON USA country has another partition. Please let me know how to perform this.

Comment: Do you use Enterprise Edition? Which version of SQL Server?

Comment: You might need to consider the potential drawbacks of partitioning. A good resource (from my point of view) is href="http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1914/sql-server-database-partitioning-myths-and-truths/", especially Myth #7...

Comment: This does not not sound like a good case for partitioning at all. You don't understand in what way it helps. You jumped to conclusions. Furthermore, it is unclear to me what you want to do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to partition large tables in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168374/what-is-the-best-way-to-partition-large-tables-in-sql-server)